# C++ - LNK 2019 Error, Trying to Define a Subclass Static Function

Tags: c++, function, static, subclass, lnk2019

The call that generates the unresolved external symbol:

```
#include <string.h>
#include "GContext.h"
#include "GBitmap.h"
#include "GColor.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const int W = 100;
    const int H = 100;
    GContext* ctx = GContext::Create(W, H);
```

The abstract class method signature:

```
#ifndef GContext_DEFINED
#define GContext_DEFINED

#include "GTypes.h"

class GBitmap;
class GColor;

class GContext {
public:
    GContext() {}
    virtual ~GContext() {}


    virtual void getBitmap(GBitmap*) const = 0;

    virtual void clear(const GColor&) = 0;


    static GContext* Create(const GBitmap&);

    static GContext* Create(int width, int height);
};

#endif
```

And the Current Derived Class Implementation and Method Signature:

```
#include "GColor.h"
#include "GPixel.h"
#include "GBitmap.h"
#include "GContext.h"
#include "GTypes.h"
class myGContext : public GContext
{
public:
        myGContext() : GContext(){}
        static const GBitmap* bitmap;

        void getBitmap(GBitmap* bitmap) const
        {

        }

        void clear(const GColor& gcolor)
        {
        int length = sizeof( (GPixel)(bitmap->fPixels) ) / sizeof(GPixel);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            (bitmap->fPixels)[i]
        }

        }

        static GContext* Create(const GBitmap& gbitmap)
        { 
        GContext::Create(gbitmap);
        bitmap = &gbitmap;
        GContext* g = new myGContext();
        return g;
        }


        static GContext* Create(int width, int height)
        {
        GContext::Create(width,height);
        GContext* g = new myGContext();
        return g;

    }
};
```

So I understand that I need to define both types of the function GContext::Create() to resolve the external symbol error, but I need to define them in my derived Class. Which I thought I was doing right, any ideas?

Comment: Did you defined you static methods inside your `GContext` class too ?

Answer (score 0):

no Inheritance does not work, this is not like a virtual function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do but if you

- Need to have static functions
- Need both base and derived classes to have their own implementation
- derived needs access to the base class' functions

this is all achievable:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    A() {}
    static void f() { std::cout << "A f" << std::endl; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() {}
    static void f() { std::cout << "B f" << std::endl; }
};




int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    A a;
    B b;

    a.f();
    b.f();
    b.A::f();
    return 0;
}
```

Output is

```
A f
B f
A f
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just because you static method is not defined in your base class. From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z.aspx) it is said that *LNK2019 can also occur when a static data member is declared but not defined.*

---

Also, be careful when you try to redefine static methods inside subclasses:

**You cannot override a static method in a subclass**, you can only hide it.

And from the C++ standard:

> **9.4.1 Static member functions [class.static.mfct]**
>
> 2/ **A `static` member function shall not be `virtual`. There shall not be a `static` and a non-static member function with the same name and the same parameter types** (13.1). A `static` member function shall not be declared `const`, `volatile`, or `const volatile`.

[Example](http://ideone.com/aDIr1K):

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
  static void func() { std::cout << "Foo::func" << std::endl; }
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
  static void func() { std::cout << "Bar::func" << std::endl; }
};

int main(void)
{
  Foo::func();     // Works
  Bar::func();     // Works

  Foo foo;
  Bar bar;

  foo.func();        // Works
  bar.func();        // Works
  bar.Foo::func();   // Works

  Foo* foobar = new Bar;

  foobar->func();      // Not the result expected
                       // Because no override.
  return 0;
}
```